# We have a request from client related to sql

Tags: sql, oracle

We have to find all the occurrences of field present in column C1 and C2.

Table client

```
C1     C2
A      X
A      X
B      Y
B      Y
```

Output Table

```
C1  C2
A    2
B    2
X    2
Y    2
```

we have single column table having teams data. we want to find all combination of matches which will happen among teams.

```
C1
A
B
C
D
```

output table

```
C1
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you do between your examples and what you expect of us!? Do you have any experience with SQL syntax?

Comment: Thanks Aleksej and B 7 for comment , will take care of these points.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the 2 questions correctly...

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tab1 AS
  2  WITH t AS
  3   (SELECT 'A' c1, 'X' c2
  4    FROM   dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 'A', 'X'
  7    FROM   dual
  8    UNION ALL
  9    SELECT 'B', 'Y'
 10    FROM   dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 'B', 'Y'
 13    FROM   dual)
 14  SELECT * FROM t;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY c1, c2;

C1  C2
--- ---
A   X
A   X
B   Y
B   Y

4 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT c1, COUNT(*) c2
  2  FROM   (SELECT c1 FROM tab1 UNION ALL SELECT c2 FROM tab1)
  3  GROUP  BY c1
  4  ORDER  BY c1;

C1   C2
--- ---
A     2
B     2
X     2
Y     2

4 rows selected.
```

And for the second part

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tab2 AS
  2  WITH t AS
  3   (SELECT CAST(column_value AS VARCHAR2(3)) c1
  4    FROM   TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')))
  5  SELECT * FROM t;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM tab2 ORDER BY c1;

C1
---
A
B
C
D

4 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT t1.c1 || t2.c1 c1 FROM tab2 t1 JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.c1 < t2.c1;

C1
---
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin for solution.